# Why are there always around 400 active bounties?

Tags: discussion

It looks to me that the number of active bounties on Stack Overflow is always close to 400. It is 392 right now. I found a comment from almost a year ago that says ["...there are currently close to 400 active bounties on Stack Overflow."](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17103/should-there-be-a-limit-on-the-number-of-bounties-active#comment63224_17103) I checked the archive.org and for a [few](https://web.archive.org/web/20140425012835/https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) [random](https://web.archive.org/web/20130626175556/https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) [samples](https://web.archive.org/web/20150224185417/https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured), I got numbers close to 400 again.

Why is it so? Why, on average, at any given time, around **400** people are willing to give rep away to get visibility on their questions?

Comment: Not sure you can draw any conclusions from that number alone. The bounty distribution among individual language tags, and their general activity / question number would be more interesting.

Comment: Because, on average, at any given time, around 400 people are willing to give rep away to get visibility on their questions? What more can we tell you? :P

Comment: @Patrice so I guess the answer is "statistics"?

Comment: @ryanyuyu What I find interesting actually is that it's been 400 since 2013. Since the userbase grew in those 2 years, does the fact we still have the same average of bounties means that most of the increase has been from crap? Depressing a bit :P

Comment: @Patrice or it could be the opposite that people find modern answer more satisfying than before and don't need to start a bounty in the first place.  I'm optimistic, and stack overflow clearly has a rose-colored color scheme.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I prefer your point of view to be honest

Comment: Also keep in mind that the more bounties there are, the less valuable bounties become (because the added attention is spread out among more questions).  This effect would tend to lead to an equilibrium point in the number of bounties.

Comment: @Patrice I used your answer as a question.

Comment: @sm4 not a problem. But I don't think that short of mind reading, there is going to be an answer

Comment: @Patrice you never know. They said similar things about economics and society and now we have models for everything ;)

Comment: I would like the bounty amount to be increased to a percentage of your current rep instead of just plainly 500.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I tried my hand at the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to see if I could gain any insights about the number of active bounties through time.

The number of active bounties increased roughly linearly from 2009 until right around 2013, and it appears to have stabilized to slightly above 400 since. A better estimate of the typical number of open bounties over the last 2.5 years is probably 425, though it fluctuates pretty widely, sometimes going below 350 or above 500:

[image]

Because the number of questions being asked on Stack Overflow has been increasing through time, this stabilization of the number of open bounties corresponds to a decreasing number of open bounties normalized by the number of questions in the past week -- since 2012 this value has decreased from about 0.01 (1 bounty per 100 questions) to roughly 0.0075 (1 bounty per ~130 questions).

[image]

One reasonable theory about why the number of bounties has decreased relative to the number of questions is that bounties are becoming less effective (and therefore awarded less frequently). While there has been a decrease in bounty effectiveness in time (though interestingly a sizable increase in 2015), this seems like a pretty minor effect:

[image]

In short, there does seem to have been a stabilization in the number of open bounties through time, which corresponds to a decreasing number of bounties per question asked. This effect probably can't be fully explained by the decreasing effectiveness of bounties (as measured by proportion of bounties awarded).

**Methodology**: I grabbed all bounty start dates and posts (these are questions) with year-specific queries like:

```sql
SELECT v.PostId, v.CreationDate FROM Votes v
  INNER JOIN Posts p ON v.PostId=p.Id
  WHERE v.VoteTypeId=8 AND YEAR(v.CreationDate) = 2009;
```

I grabbed each year separately to get around the limit of 50,000 records returned by the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. Note that this is an inner join with the Posts table, so bounties on posts that no longer exist were ignored (this is a small number of posts).

I similarly grabbed all bounty end dates and posts (these are either questions, when ParentId is missing, or answers, when ParentId is present) with:

```sql
SELECT v.PostId, p.ParentId, v.CreationDate FROM Votes v 
  INNER JOIN Posts p ON v.PostId=p.Id
  WHERE v.VoteTypeId=9 AND YEAR(v.CreationDate) = 2009;
```

Finally, I grabbed the number of new questions on each day with:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date, CreationDate), Count(*) FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId=1 GROUP BY CONVERT(date, CreationDate);
```

If the list of all csv files for results from the first queries are in variable `add.csv`, the list of all csv files for results from the second query are in variable `sub.csv`, and results of the third query are in file `numq.csv`, then you can run the following R code to match bounty start and end times (throwing away starts and ends that are not matched) and generate all the plots:

```r
# Read in bounty start and end, combining into data frame dat
dat1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(add.csv, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=F))
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sub.csv, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=F))
dat2$FullId <- ifelse(is.na(dat2$ParentId), dat2$PostId, dat2$ParentId)
dat <- data.frame(id=c(dat1$PostId, dat2$FullId),
                  date=c(dat1$CreationDate, dat2$CreationDate),
                  add=c(rep(T, nrow(dat1)), rep(F, nrow(dat2))))
dat$date <- as.numeric(as.Date(dat$date) - as.Date("2009-01-01"))

# Throw away start or end indicators that are not matched
spl <- split(dat, dat$id)
spl.keep <- lapply(spl, function(x) {
  add.day <- x$date[x$add]
  sub.day <- x$date[!x$add]
  if (length(add.day) == 0 || length(sub.day) == 0) return(NULL)
  keep.add <- sapply(add.day, function(y) sum(sub.day >= y & sub.day <= y+8) > 0)
  keep.sub <- sapply(sub.day, function(y) sum(add.day <= y & add.day >= y-8) > 0)
  data.frame(date=c(add.day[keep.add], sub.day[keep.sub]),
             add=c(rep(T, sum(keep.add)), rep(F, sum(keep.sub))))
})
grouped <- do.call(rbind, spl.keep)

# Determine the number of bounties at each date
diffs <- aggregate(add~date, data=grouped, function(x) sum(x) - sum(!x))
final <- data.frame(date=diffs$date + as.Date("2009-01-01"),
                    numBounty=cumsum(diffs$add))
final <- head(final, -10)

# Generate plot 1
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(final, aes(x=date, y=numBounty)) + geom_line() + stat_smooth() + ylim(0, 600) + xlab("Year") + ylab("Number of Open Bounties") + theme_bw()

# Load the number of questions on each day, calculating number of questions in last week
numQ <- read.csv(numq.csv, stringsAsFactors=F)
names(numQ) <- c("Date", "NumQ")
numQ$Date <- as.Date(numQ$Date)
numQ <- numQ$NumQ[match(final$date, numQ$Date)]
l7Q <- head(numQ, -7) + head(tail(numQ, -1), -6) + head(tail(numQ, -2), -5) + head(tail(numQ, -3), -4) + head(tail(numQ, -4), -3) + head(tail(numQ, -5), -2) + head(tail(numQ, -6), -1) + tail(numQ, -7)
final <- tail(final, -7)
final$l7Q <- l7Q
final$propBounty <- final$numBounty / final$l7Q

# Generate plot 2
ggplot(final, aes(x=date, y=propBounty)) + geom_line() + stat_smooth() + theme_bw() + ylim(0, 0.015) + xlab("Year") + ylab("Number of Open Bounties / Num Questions in Last Week")

# Generate plot 3
dat.play <- dat2
dat.play$Assigned <- as.numeric(!is.na(dat.play$ParentId))
dat.play$CreationDate <- as.Date(dat.play$CreationDate)
ggplot(dat.play, aes(x=CreationDate, y=Assigned)) + stat_smooth() + theme_bw() + ylim(0, 1) + xlab("Year") + ylab("Proportion of Bounties Awarded")
```

Comment: I've seen recently the number go up to 450 and now it's 388. It behaves like stock market. From your charts it looks like there really is a point where bounties lose value and their numbers drop. Then they increase value again. The bouncing is probably caused by random clusters of bounties. I wonder if introduction of new versions of libraries causes and stir. Anyway, very well done.

Answer (score -11):

I don’t know if it is just me….

But over the last 5 years I have found that bounties have had a lot less effect in getting a good answer.     Therefore I am a lot less likely to offer one.

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that almost all of your bounties are for 50 or 100 rep, and that 25 of the 26 bounties you've offered are on questions that now have accepted answers.

Comment: @Servy,  In the "old days" a bounty of 50 rep would get a lot of response, it does not any more.    I think your comment on the question is correct, in that a equilibrium point is reached in the number of bounties.     I expect it is the number of bounties that is key, not the total rep on offer.